# Thymeleaf form validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to validate password via double check and display an error with thymeleaf if passwords don't match

The input form looks like this

```java
package com.foxminded.university.domain;

import javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class UserForm {

    @NotNull(message = "Can't be empty")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30, message = "Must be more than 2 and less than 30 symbols")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message = "Can't be empty")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30, message = "Must be more than 2 and less than 30 symbols")
    private String lastName;

    @Email(message = "Enter valid e-mail" )
    private String email;

    @Pattern(regexp = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})",
    message = "Enter valid password")
    private String password;

    private String passwordRepeat;

    private boolean passwordsEqual;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getPasswordRepeat() {
        return passwordRepeat;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setPasswordRepeat(String passwordRepeat) {
        this.passwordRepeat = passwordRepeat;
    }

    public void setPasswordsEqual(boolean passwordsEqual) {
        this.passwordsEqual = passwordsEqual;
    }
    @AssertTrue(message = "Passwords should match")
    public boolean isPasswordsEqual() {
        return password.equals(passwordRepeat);
    }
}
```

And thymeleaf form row:

```html
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="text" th:unless="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                   th:field="*{password}">
            <input type="text" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" class="form-control alert-danger"
                   placeholder="Password" th:field="*{password}">
            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Repeat password</label>
            <input type="text" th:unless="${#fields.hasErrors('passwordsEqual')}" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Password" th:field="*{passwordRepeat}">
            <input type="text" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('passwordsEqual')}" class="form-control alert-danger"
                   placeholder="Password" th:field="*{passwordRepeat}">
            <span class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('passwordsEqual')}" th:errors="*{passwordsEqual}"></span>
        </div><div class="form-group">
            <label> Repeat password</label>
            <input type="text" th:unless="${#fields.hasErrors('passwordsEqual')}" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Password" th:field="*{passwordRepeat}">
            <input type="text" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('passwordsEqual')}" class="form-control alert-danger"
                   placeholder="Password" th:field="*{passwordRepeat}">
            <span class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('passwordsEqual')}" th:errors="*{passwordsEqual}"></span>
        </div>
```

But with this setup it doesn't load with exception `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.foxminded.university.domain.UserForm.isPasswordsEqual(UserForm.java:74)`

So I'm not sure what should I annotate in from and whuch field to use in thymeleaf template for it to work?

Comment: I believe you have a type in markup.First input should have th:field="*{**password**}"> (not passwordRepeat)

Comment: right, there's a "password" input above, didn't mention it, but fixed in edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the password is null in any runtime,
Try to add a validation to avoid nullpointer.

```
 @AssertTrue(message = "PasswisPasswordsEqualords should match")
    public boolean isPasswordsEqual() {
        return (password == null) ? false : password.equals(passwordRepeat);
    }
```

Comment: the form itself can't be loaded, even without field values

Answer (score 0):

Validation Interceptor tries to validate all added constraints and return them all. Your validation method throws NullPointerException and stops it.

Add NotEmpty constraint on your password field.

```
@Pattern(regexp = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})",
message = "Enter valid password")
@NotEmpty
private String password;
```

Catch NullPointerException and return false.

```
@AssertTrue(message = "Passwords should match")
public boolean isPasswordsEqual() {
    try {
        return password.equals(passwordRepeat);
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```